# How can I remove something from the middle of a string with regex?

Tags: regex

I have strings which look like this:

```
/xxxxx/xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-338200.html
```

With my regex:

```
(?<=-)(\d+)(?=\.html)
```

It matches just the numbers before `.html`.

Is it possible to write a regex that matches everything that surrounds the numbers (matches the `.html` part and the part before the numbers)?

Comment: What tool/language are you using here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current pattern you already use a capturing group. In that case you might also match what comes before and after instead of using the lookarounds

```
-(\d+)\.html
```

To get what comes before and after the digits, you could use 2 capturing groups:

```
^(.*-)\d+(\.html)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vmjE4y/1)

In the replacement use the 2 groups.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
.*-\d+\.html
```

**Explanation**: `.*` will match anything until `-\d+` say it should match a - followed by a sequence of digits before a `\.html` (where `\.` represents the character `.`).

To capture groups, just do `(.*-)(\d+)(\.html)`. This will put everything before the number in a group, the number in another group and everything after the number in another group.